# html download attribute not supported in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, internet-explorer-11

I'm writing Angularjs.
This is my code(That works fine in chrome):

```
<a download="a.json" ng-click="updateExport()" ng-href="{{exportUrl}}" translate="Export"></a>
```

In explorer (IE11) - When I click on this code, the function `updateExport()` calls. but `ng-href` and download didn't started. I saw that explorer don't support `download` attribute. How can I change my code to support chrome, Firefox and Explorer at the same time? (Without jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used [this library](https://github.com/ChenWenBrian/FileSaver.js#examples) to solve the compatibility issue. Right now, it can be downloaded in Chrome and IE. Below is part of my code:

```
var csv = Papa.unparse(data);
var blob = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
try {
    var isFileSaverSupported = !!blob;
    saveAs(blob, filename);
} catch (e) {
    console.debug('File Saver is not supported. try upgrade your browser. Thank you.', e);
    saveTextAs(csv, filename);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I meet the same issue and here has a brief overview for the browser compatibility.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp
Download attribute only support IE 13 or later.

Comment: I won't say posting this as an answer is wrong but it would be more meaningful if you post the essential portions of the answer.